# Browser-Extension failing to load font due to Content Security Policy

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser-extension, cross-origin-resource-policy

I'm working on a browser extension and wanted to change the font of a page, due to not being able to find any resources on how to do this i attempted to solve this by using the following code:

```js
// content.js

const style = document.createElement('style');
style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300;400;500&display=swap)`));
document.head.appendChild(style);
```

the browser then fails while attempting to fetch this file, erroring out with:

```
> Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300;400;500&display=swap (“style-src”).
```

I'm not sure how to change the CSP or adapt my css/js to it.

### Other information

Tested on: Firefox V105.0.1 (64-bit) Windows 10

```json
// manifest.json
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Test-Extension",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "all_frames": true,
            "matches": ["*"],
            "js": ["build/content.js"],
            "css": ["build/content.css"]
        }
    ]
}
```

```css
/* content.css */
*, html {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif !important;
}
```